# Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, floating-action-button, runtimeexception

My app crashed because

> Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

This is my code in the XML

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_right"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/green"
        android:onClick="previewphoto"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
```

and here is my gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0' // appcompat library
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
```

my logcat

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.cyanlabsid.cetakphoto, PID: 15298
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.cyanlabsid.cetakphoto/com.cyanlabsid.cetakphoto.PhotoPicker}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #76: Binary XML
>   file line #76: Error inflating class
>   android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2423)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628) Caused
>   by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #76: Binary
>   XML file line #76: Error inflating class
>   android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:543) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>   at com.cyanlabsid.cetakphoto.PhotoPicker.onCreate(PhotoPicker.java:74)
>   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483) 
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349) 
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738) 
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)

Can somebody tell my fault?

Comment: If you are using android studio, try "Invalidate caches and restart" (from file menu).

Comment: which OS version are you running this on and is your `@drawable/icon_right` a vector drawable?

Comment: is   `xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` ?

Comment: if you are extending Activity to your ActivityClass please change it to AppCompatActivity.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Tried your code, the problem is with the 23.4.0 library.

Upgrade to 24.+ , there's no error in that lib.

For example :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1' // appcompat library
implementation 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
```

You need to change the compile version to 24 too.

```
compileSdkVersion 24
```

Comment: using version 27, still same problem

Comment: `compile` is deprecated, use `implementation`

Comment: API 22 is not wok

Comment: just need to use app:backgroundTint  not android:backgroundTint which will work for all time

Comment: @HarshilPansare you can migrate your app to androidx then your issue will be solved

Answer (score 57):

Use

```
app:backgroundTint
```

in stead of

```
android:backgroundTint
```

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 22):

Because `android:backgroundTint` doesn't work below android API 21, so you need to use `app:backgroundTint` instead.

Answer (score 14):

Below API level 21 app versions not support for the

```
app:backgroundTint="@color/green"
```

or you can use this library for achieve more material design widgets.

> https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary

happy coding...

Answer (score 13):

You need to add

> android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"

in the XML_Layout file in which you are using FloatingActionButton...

Comment: ...+1 This was the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

**I had the same problem**

I faced the same issue with Pre-Lolipop version and to resolve it, I just changed "**android:src**" to "**app:srcCompat**"  & it worked for me.

To make compatibility with older version and if you're using a Vector graphics (as drawable assets) you should use:

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/you_graphics"
```

instead of:

```
android:src="@drawable/your_graphics"
```

Comment: We have to change remaining attributes as well if required.
        app:tint="@android:color/white"
        app:backgroundTint="#FF5722"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appBar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"

Answer (score 5):

I am using:

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'

and

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip

I changed my XML to:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/mapit"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/foundit_imageView"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
```

and everything built and ran correctly.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

```
 <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_foreground"
        android:layout_margin="16dp" />
```

Use this

```
 <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton>
```

instead of

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the library from which you declared the **FloatingActionButton** in the activity is the same as the one used for the layout markup

For example have

**import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;** in the activity and
**com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton** as the tag for the layout

Answer (score 1):

I was using Material Design for my ExtendedFloatingActionButton and when using API 24 it would crash the app.

I tried updating my gradle dependencies to the latest version:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha02'
```

but I had no luck with that either. My solution was adding `android:theme=""` even though I had set a style it would still crash so I set the theme to the same as the style and it worked perfectly.

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_one"
                    android:theme="@style/"
                    style="@style/"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/text"
                    android:text="@string/text"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Add in

> build.gradle(:app)

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'
```

Use this in your XML

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_right"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/green"
        android:onClick="previewphoto"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code it will be work better ;

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:backgroundTint="#f9fcfc"

        android:src="@drawable/chat_float"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop" />
```