# 'Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton'

Tags: android

Android.Views.InflateException: 'Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton'

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@mipmap/baseline_add_24"
        app:tint="@color/white"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

Please help in this problem, doesn't work on Android 7.1 API  25

Comment: Try and have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42221530/error-inflating-class-android-support-design-widget-floatingactionbutton You should find your answer.

Comment: @Mihai nothing works from that.....

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd post the actual error from logcat.

Answer (score 0):

According to Android [FloatingActionButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton), the class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton has been superseded by androidx and is no longer maintained. Google provide a [new FloatingActionButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/floatingactionbutton/FloatingActionButton) class in androidx material design, you're recommended to use this instead:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
    app:tint="@color/white"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary" />
```